# alignParentBottom appears Offscreen in Fragment with Scroll View

Tags: android, user-interface, alignment, android-relativelayout

For those wanting to have an adView in their app that is comprised of Fragment layouts, hope the below helps you!

Basically, I was originally trying to place the adView inside the Layout XML for each fragment.  This caused the adView to either be pushed off the screen or not play nice with the relative layout commands (ex. alignParentBottom).

The solution was to move the adView into the Main Activity Layout outside of the the Coordinator Layout used for my fragments.  Then I wrapped the Coordinator Layout and adView in a Relative Layout.

This then allowed me to fully control the adView and present on each fragment pinned to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I haven't tested and not sure it will give you what you want but what if you use `alignParentBottom` for your ad view and align your `ScrollView` above the ad view with `android:layout_above`?

Comment: Weird got this when I tried your suggestion. Error:(98, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').

Comment: I think your problem is that the AdView is before the ScrollView in the code. The ScrollView MIGHT be drawing over the AdView. Try putting the AdView below the ScrollView. Also, make sure your Ad Unit ID and everything is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that when I change the background of your ScrollView, it paints OVER the AdView. You MUST place your AdView below the ScrollView in code. That way, it is drawn AFTER the ScrollView and is therefore on top.

Here is your edited code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <!-- Dummy item to prevent EditTextView from receiving focus -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummyLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <!-- Dummy item to prevent EditTextView from receiving focus -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="4"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/editText1"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/editText1"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView4"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent0"
        android:stretchColumns="*"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:background="@color/colorGray">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tossed the adview above the scroll view after reading a much older SO thread.  Should have tried reversing that earlier hah.

Comment: Sorry, I got faked out moving adview below scroll view still not appearing on screen

Comment: That's weird because I got it to show up on my device with the code I pasted above. Maybe try `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"` as well.

Comment: Looks like that helped.  Its on the screen now and below the scroll view but not pinned to the bottom of the screen (moves up/down with the scroll view).  Maybe because the layout is a Fragment?

Comment: Try setting your ScrollView to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`,  setting your ScrollView to `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` and removing `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"`

Comment: Gave it a shot and the adview is off the screen.  The scroll view looks like it is pinned to the bottom of the screen with a big gap between the top of the scroll view and the earlier views on the screen.  Maybe I'll just copy paste your original code snippet into a fresh project and work backwards from there.  One more thing to note is the table view inside the scroll view has rows added to it programatically depending on user input.

Comment: I just edited your code again and it is working for me. I just changed it in my answer. Let me know if it still isn't working for you.

Comment: Your suggestions led me to figure it out!  Thank you!  Your edited code worked perfect in a brand new raw app.  So I decided to move the ad view out of the fragments completely and put in the main activity layout outside my coordinator layout.  Then wrapped the coordinator layout and the adview inside a relative layout.